# React Native Render HTML with custom tags

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to create custom tags using this [lib](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html) but i got error

> There is no custom renderer registered for tag "red" which is not part
> of the HTML5 standard.

So my code so far

```
    const source = {
      html: `
    <red>
      dsfsd
    </red>
    `,
    };
    
    const tagsStyles = {
      red: {
        color: "red",
      },
    };
<RenderHtml
 contentWidth={width}
tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
source={source}
/>
```

I am pretty sure that there is way that i can create text red but i cant really find it.
What should i do? If anyone has experience with this library i will be very heppy!